# dynamic arrays and operator overloading cause memory crash

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, memory-leaks, operator-overloading

To illustrate my problem I minimalize my source:

```
#include <iostream>
class vec{
    public:
    float* X;
    int DIM;
    vec(int dimension)
    {
        DIM = dimension;
        X = new float[dimension];
        for (int i=0;i<DIM;i++)
            X[i] = (float) rand()/RAND_MAX;
    }
    ~vec(void){
        delete [] X;
    }

    vec operator-( vec const& rhs )
    {
        vec ans(DIM);
        for (int i=0;i<DIM;i++)
            ans.X[i] = X[i] - rhs.X[i];
        return ans;
    }
};

int main(){
    vec A(5),B(5),C(5);
    C= A-B;
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this program I get an error that a heap was destroyed. I am pretty sure that the destructor is my problem. In the line with `C= A-B;` the variable `ans` will be destroyed by the constructor and cannot be returned. Is that right? 
If I delete the line `delete [] X;` everything is ok. But it won't free up the memory.

I did my homework and consult one of the most famous search engine for this problem but didn't find any answer. How can I fix it?

Comment: `ans` getting destructed is not a problem. A temporary copy of `ans` is made and that is what is returned (in principle.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C = A-B` calls the default copy-assignment operator (as you haven't defined one).  Therefore two different objects will point to the same dynamically-allocated array.

You need to read up on the [*Rule of Three*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (in a nutshell: if you define any of the destructor, the copy constructor or the copy-assignment operator, you probably need to define them all).

But preferably, you should avoid using raw arrays entirely; use a container type that manages its own memory.

Comment: "use a container type that manages its own memory" That's what should be done. The basic is `std::vector`, although in the OP's case, I would also consider `std::valarray`.

Comment: Solution:
void operator=(vec const& rhs)
 {
  for (int i=0;i<DIM;i++)
   X[i] = rhs.X[i];
 }
?? Or is there sth I have to do, too?

Comment: Thanks that was the point I didn't saw. Sorry for this stupid question.